# np.array reset cumsum at np.nan

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
 np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 2, 4, np.nan, 5, 1, 2, 1, np.nan, 10])
```

I want to split it and sum.

Expected output:

```
np.array([10, 6, 9, 10])
```

Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy and set `nan` to 0, and then use `numpy.add.reduceat` to sum:

```
>>> mask = np.isnan(ar)
>>> arr = np.where(mask, 0, ar)
>>> mask[0] = True
>>> np.add.reduceat(arr, mask.nonzero()[0])
array([10.,  6.,  9., 10.])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it...

```
# create array
arr=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 2, 4, np.nan, 5, 1, 2, 1, np.nan, 10])
# find arguments where array elements are nan
argsnan=np.argwhere(np.isnan(arr)).flatten()
# split array into list of arrays
list_of_arrays = np.split(arr, argsnan)
# sum up with list comprehension
list_sum = [np.sum(arr[np.isfinite(arr)]) for arr in list_of_arrays]
```